# How to add the total number of slides in a footer?

Tags: beamer, footer

```
I'd like to insert the number of slides into the footer of my presentation. How could I do that? This is my ME:

\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{framed,color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%footline%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace*{-8pt}Title\hfill\insertshortsubtitle\hfill\insertpagenumber}}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\title{\textbf{A title}}
\subtitle{A subtitle}
\author{My name}
\date{}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the following in your defined `\parbox` environment and then compile:

```
\parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace*{-8pt}Title\hfill\insertshortsubtitle\hfill\strut\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your indication.